# sed or grep or awk to match very very long lines

Tags: perl, sed, awk, grep

more file

```
param1=" 1,deerfntjefnerjfntrjgntrjnvgrvgrtbvggfrjbntr*rfr4fv*frfftrjgtrignmtignmtyightygjn      2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 
rfcmckmfdkckemdio8u548384omxc,mor0ckofcmineucfhcbdjcnedjcnywedpeodl40fcrcmkedmrikmckffmcrffmrfrifmtrifmrifvysdfn drfr4fdr4fmedmifmitfmifrtfrfrfrfnurfnurnfrunfrufnrufnrufnrufnruf"****
```

need to match the content of param1 as

```
sed -n "/$param1/p" file
```

but because the line length (very long line) I cant match the line
what’s the best way to match very long lines?

Comment: Don't you mean `sed -n "/^param1/p"`? "$" matches the end of line; "^" the beginning.

Comment: There’s no restriction on the length of the line. Please be more specific: where exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Dav The $ is shell variable substitution.

Comment: @David, $param1 is a variable substitution, note the double quotes

Comment: NO $param1 include all the follwoing line:
1,deerfntjefnerjfntrjgntrjnvgrvgrtbvggfrjbntr*rfr4fv*frfftrjgtrignmtignmtyightygjn      2,3,4,5,6,7,8,  
rfcmckmfdkckemdio8u548384omxc,mor0ckofcmineucfhcbdjcnedjcnywedpeodl40fcrcmkedmrikmckffmcrffmrfrifmtrifmrifvysdfn drfr4fdr4fmedmifmitfmifrtfrfrfrfnurfnurnfrunfrufnrufnrufnrufnruf"

Comment: the question is how to match very very long lines because with sed / grep its not work?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that param1 contains special characters which are being interpreted by sed.  The asterisk ('*') is used to mean 'zero or more occurrences of the previous character', so when this character is interpreted by sed there is nothing left to match the literal asterisk you are looking for.

The following is a working bash script that should help:

```
#!/bin/bash

param1=' 1,deerfntjefnerjfntrjgntrjnvgrvgrtbvggfrjbntr\*rfr4fv\*frfftrjgtrignmtignmtyightygjn 2,3,4,5,6,7,8, rfcmckmfdkckemdio8u548384omxc,mor0ckofcmineucfhcbdjcnedjcnywedpeodl40fcrcmkedmrikmckffmcrffmrfrifmtrifmrifvysdfn'

cat <<EOF | sed "s/${param1}/Bubba/g"
 1,deerfntjefnerjfntrjgntrjnvgrvgrtbvggfrjbntr*rfr4fv*frfftrjgtrignmtignmtyightygjn 2,3,4,5,6,7,8, rfcmckmfdkckemdio8u548384omxc,mor0ckofcmineucfhcbdjcnedjcnywedpeodl40fcrcmkedmrikmckffmcrffmrfrifmtrifmrifvysdfn    
EOF
```

Comment: THX but I not need to replace the line only to match like grep
the target is to verify matching
yael

Comment: This is just an example to illustrate the problem you were having.  The intent was for you to focus on the issue (you have special characters in your matching expression), not the way I'm using it.  Obviously you wouldn't be replacing your match with 'Bubba'.

Comment: @yael: Why don't you just use `grep`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is that your `$param1` contains special characters? This works for me:

```
A="$(perl -e 'print "a" x 10000')"
echo $A | sed -n "/$A/p"
```

(`$A` contains 10 000 `a` characters).

```
echo $A | grep -F $A
```

and

```
echo $A | grep -P $A
```

also works (second requires grep with built-in PCRE support. If you want pattern matching you should use either this or pcregrep. If you don't, use the fixed grep (`grep -F`)).

```
echo $A | grep $A
```

is too slow.

Comment: can I get more usful solution from perl?